# NAs When Calculating 95%CI of Median Survival?

Tags: confidence-interval, survival, median

When I try to find 95% CI of quartile estimates of survival (including median), I get NAs for upper limits of CI.
I use
`survfit(Surv(time = SURV_DURATION, event = CENSOR) ~ RESPONSE, data = data, conf.type = "log-log")` to fit my model and as I understood it uses uses a generalization of the Brookmeyer and
Crowley (1982) sign test to find the CI.
But why I get NAs for upper limits ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get `NA` because not enough people have died yet to estimate the upper confidence.

Leaving out the precise details of how it's done in R, conceptually the way to get a confidence interval for median survival is to get a confidence interval for the survival curve and cut it at 50%. If the upper limit of the survival curve hasn't reached 50%, there is no estimate for the upper confidence limit on the median.

Using other techniques to get an upper limit (such as inverting a score test) doesn't change the basic idea: you can't get an upper confidence limit on the median until you can be confident the true survival curve is down below 50%

Comment: Thanks for explanation